# SDL_LoadBMP() displaying a black surface while surface is referenced

Tags: c++, sdl

Trying to load an image onto an SDL_Surface. However the surface is always black although the bmp is clearly not.

NOTE

This is a working SDL_Window and creating a surface pointer is successful, what is unsuccessful is loading "Kassadin.bmp" which is located in the Code::Blocks project folder. It displays a black surface.

ALL answers on this particular question have NOT solved this problem, before marking this as a duplicate.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <SDL.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  using namespace std;

  const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 700;
  const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  //Create an SDL_Window pointer
  SDL_Window* window = NULL;

  //Create an SDL_Surface pointer
  SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

  //SDL_Surface for an image
  SDL_Surface* imgSurface = NULL;

  bool init(){
  //try init SDL
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
    cout << "Failed init SDL" << endl;
    return false;
  }else{

    //create window           title            x pos                    y  pos                    width         height         flags
    //This doesnt include a surface ie it will be a plain window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("An SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

}

if(window == NULL){
    cout << "Failed creating SDL window" << endl;
    return false;
}else{
    // creates surface with an SDL_Window object
    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
}
return true;
}

bool loadMedia(){
imgSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("Kassadin.bmp");

return true;
}

void close(){
//Sets the SDL_Window pointer to NULL again
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

window = NULL;

SDL_FreeSurface (imgSurface);
imgSurface = NULL;

//quits
SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

if(!init()){
    cout << "error init sdl" << endl;
}else{

    if(!loadMedia){
        cout << "Trouble loading media..." << endl;
    }else{

        SDL_BlitSurface(imgSurface, NULL, surface, NULL);

    }

}

//This is so it's not just a static window ie it can update
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

SDL_Delay(5000);

close();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problemmatic line is

```
if(!loadMedia){
```

It is not a function call. What it does is checks address of function `loadMedia` is NULL, which is always false because function address assigned by linker (as opposed to funciton pointers which you manually assign at runtime).

As you mentioned codeblocks, I suppose you use gcc to compile your code. If only you've added at least `-Wall` flag (which is a very good practice) compiler would have warned you that you're doing something that very much looks like a mistake:

```
test2.cpp:70:9: warning: the address of ‘bool loadMedia()’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
```

Comment: Fixed, the syntax error but it STILL is returning a blac

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Output `imgSurface` value and `SDL_GetError()` before blitting then (or examine in debugger). Event loop would be nice but it doesn't seem to be the problem here, although I would've started by flushing event queue if pointer is nonnull and there is no errors.